# Can I miror Nikon D5000 live view to an android device wirelessly/wired?

Tags: video, nikon, mobile

I am using my Nikon D5000 to record some videos. The problem is that at some points the camera will be mounted on a crane and while I would be able to operate it's orientation, I won't see the image. I know that a solution is to get a small monitor and pass the micro HDMI through an adapter and then to the monitor, but I was wondering if there might be a way to wirelessly or by cable transmit the feed directly to my Android phone that would be able to display it, most probably by using a special app.

I found [this device](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/HDMI-AnyCast-M2-Plus-1080P-Wireless-WiFi-same-screen-device-Miracast-phone-projection-TV-transmitter-Free/32663967019.html), but this one outputs from Android to another screen, and I want to receive the data from the camera and display it to my phone.

Is this possible? If so, how?